# android editText is cursor visible?

Tags: android, cursor, android-edittext, visible

Is there any way to know if on a edit text is visible or not the cursor? I need to know so I can adapt a delete method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> public static final int **getSelectionStart (CharSequence text)** Since:
>   API Level 1
>
> Return the offset of the selection anchor or cursor, or -1 if there is
>   no selection or cursor.

So if it returns -1 you know there is no cursor.

**EDIT:**

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            // cursor visible!!!
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: if I have more than 2 edit texts, with some text in them, if the user taps on first, getSelectionStart returns a value and if the user taps on the second editText, the cursor became invisible in the first editText but getSelectionStart returns the same value and not -1 as you stated

Comment: That's not true for the case where the user has selected some text. The edit text will then have focus, but the cursor is not shown.